# CFNetwork internal error : URLConnectionLoader.cpp:289

Tags: ios, xcode, cfnetwork

When I open my application after a while, I received log:

> 440: CFNetwork internal error (0xc01a:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/CFNetwork/CFNetwork-758.4.3/Loading/URLConnectionLoader.cpp:289)

It has never been out in the past.
My project uses a network library AFNetworking and CocoaAsyncSocket.

Why does it occur and how to fix it?

Comment: Show some of your code

Comment: sorry, I do not know which piece of code cause the log and clean this still appears

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my situation, it is not AFNetwork's issue, I use a invalid SSL certification and SDWebImage, when use the option 'SDWebImageAllowInvalidSSLCertificates' in SDWebImage and get a http image (not https image), you will get this error. the protocol (http or https) not being recognized automaticly by SDWebImage.

my solution:
I not change SDWebImage’s code, I just write a wrapper for recognized protocol (http or https). 
I use '0' option for http images and 'SDWebImageAllowInvalidSSLCertificates' option for https images (my https certification is self signed or invalid). If yours cer is valid , I think SDWebImage works well.

Comment: I rewrite my answer

Comment: Care to provide your source code? This would be helpful, in the same situation.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue by adding using below attributes in your `info.plist`

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>http://mydomain</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```