# CFNetwork internal error : URLConnectionLoader.cpp:304

Tags: ios, objective-c

When I open my application after a while, I received lots of the same log:

9060:CFNetwork internal error (0xc01a:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/CFNetwork_Sim/CFNetwork-808.2.16/Loading/URLConnectionLoader.cpp:304)

And then my app crashed. This happens after I used the library MJRefresh from github (https://github.com/CoderMJLee/MJRefresh).

My project uses libraries as below:
AFNetworking, CocoaLumberjack, MBProgressHUD, MJRefresh, SDAutoLayout, SDWebImage and WebViewJavascriptBridge.

I google the error message, but I didn't find any solution.
Below link is nearly the same problem with mine, but I still don't know how to solve my problem.
[CFNetwork internal error : URLConnectionLoader.cpp:289](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38050726/cfnetwork-internal-error-urlconnectionloader-cpp289)

Comment: By digging deeper, I am wondering if the problem is SDWebImage, anybody  encountered such problem before?

Comment: Finally, I found out there are 2 problems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally, I found out there are 2 problems. 
1. Downloaded images are too large(nearly 10M each for 12 pictures), which made the memory run out, and then my app crashed. 
2. I used `sd_setImageWithURL:(nullable NSURL *)url placeholderImage:`, if images are not exist, the **CFNetwork internal error** will appear, and after a while the connection to server will break and my app can't get any data from server. Then I used `sd_setImageWithURL:(nullable NSURL *)url completed:` to solve such problem. Although the CFNetwork error still occurs, but the connection will not break any more.

Comment: I have the same problem, it is caused by SDWebImage, when the image that I want to download returns 304 status code.